# How to target small phones 3 inch or lesser with media query

Tags: css, media-queries, mobile-phones

I am trying to target small phones like 3 to 3.5 inches 
for Example:

```
HTC DESIRE C
```

using `@mediaQUery` but not able to do that .

I could target the standard mobile phone width that is as follow.

```
@media only screen and (min-device-width : 320px) and (orientation : portrait) {
    .bar {
        display:none !important;
    }
}
@media only screen and (min-width : 321px) and (orientation : landscape) {
    /* Styles */
    .par {
        display:none !important;
    }
}
```

[**JSFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/65ec9tyc/2/)

So what I want to do is show the class `.par` only when the width of the screen is equivalent to 3inch phones

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most of the resolution will fall within `320px`

So you have to changes min to below code

```
@media screen and (max-width: 320px){
/*YOUR CODE */
}
```

Comment: yes I understand that. Actually I wanted to show a div with class `.bar` when the phone screen width is 4 to 4.5 inches and hide it when the width is 3 to 2.5inches and  display another div with class`.par` . But the problem is even 4.5 inches phone has the same 320 resolution :(

Comment: also I was trying to target samsung galaxy S4 and Moto G separately. S4 has 4.99 inch screen and moto G has 4.5 screen still the with is same 360 px so any idea how I can do this ?